# How to write an async function in the constructor of typescript

Tags: typescript, function, async-await, ionic4

I would like to know, whether there is a way to write an async function in the constructor in Typescript (Ionic 4: Angular). I only want to read out a json file, but need it in the whole code and want to trigger the function by the beginning. This is what I want to call in the constructor.

```
async ReadFile(filename: string, fileFunktion: string) {
    this.data = await this.http.get(filename).toPromise();
    return this.data;
  }
```

Is there a way to call this in the constructor?

Comment: Yes you can. A constructor can't be async, as far as I know, but you can still use promises.

Comment: Don't put async function in constructor. You cannot await a constructor. Just call it from you calling code i.e. `const c = new Class(); await c.ReadFile()`; A constructor should just be used to create an instance of its class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your async function as a promise

```js
class YourClass {

  constructor() {
    ReadFile(filename, fileFunction)
      .then(data => /* do something */);
  }

}
```